# No puedo importar desde dentro de una función javascript

Tags: javascript, importación

estoy empezando con javascript y me ha surgido un problema que no consigo solucionar por mucho que he mirado en la web. Quiero hacer un import desde dentro de una función y me da error. Ese mismo código lo saco fuera de la función y funciona sin problemas.
Muestro un ejemplo:

**Archivo envia.js**

```
export function suma(a,b){
    var suma = a+b;
    return suma;
}
```

**Archivo recibe.js**------------De esta manera me da error--------------

```
function importar(){
    import {suma} from './envia.js';
    var lasuma = suma(90,8);
    console.log(lasuma);
}
importar();
```

**Archivo recibe.js**------------De esta manera funciona--------------

```
import {suma} from './envia.js';
var lasuma = suma(90,8);
console.log(lasuma);

function importar(){
    
}
importar();
```

Pero yo lo que necesito es importar dentro de la función
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La sintaxis

```
import {suma} from './envia.js';
```

implica importación estática: siempre ocurre y debe ser declarada al inicio del fichero, no se puede hacer dentro de una función.

Pero existe otra sintaxis:

```
import('./envia.js').then (module => {
   module.suma(...);
});
```

Que es dinámica: ocurre cuando se pide y no antes.

Usando async/await y desestructuración podemos reescribir tu código así, mucho más fácil de leer que con promesas:

```
async function importar(){
    const {suma} = await import('./envia.js');
    var lasuma = suma(90,8);
    console.log(lasuma);
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-h77dfh?file=script.js) (los fragmentos ejecutables de StackOverflow no permiten declarar varios ficheros Javascript, así que no puedo añadir una demostración dentro de la respuesta)

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, ya funciona perfectamente. Me has quitado un problema que me tenía ya cansado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar de seguir esta lógica:

```js
selectEx();
function selectEx(){
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(){
        switch(parseInt(this.value)){
            case 1:
                (async () => {
                let u01 = await require("./modules/ultimate-001.js");
                u01();
                })();
                break;
        }
    });
};

async function require(path) {
    let _module = window.module;
    window.module = {};
    await import(path);
    let exports = module.exports;
    window.module = _module;
    return exports;
};
```

En mi caso lo hice hace muchio con un switch donde yo elegía la opción que quería exportar. Tu podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Quita el querySelector
2. Quita el eventListener
3. Haz que la función retorne el módulo que tu quieres poner

La lógica detrás de cómo importar desde el top-level del documento sin que esté necesariamente en el top-level es esta. Luego ya como quieras/vayas a hacerlo es cosa tuya. :)
Espero que te sirva.